# Concatenate .x from a purrr function with string and loop over column list

Tags: r, purrr

Say I have this df:

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
            ~weight,    ~country,  ~thing_MASTER_s, ~thingy_blue_s, ~thing_red_s,   ~thingy_yellow_s, ~thingy_orange_s, ~thingy_brown_s, ~thingy_pink_s, ~thingy_purple_s,
            1.93218,   "Germany",             1.0,            1.00,           NA,                 NA,               NA,         NA,                  NA,             1.00,
            0.84321,   "Germany",             1.0,            1.00,           NA,                 NA,               NA,         NA,                  NA,             1.00,
            1.11002,   "Germany",             NA,             0.75,           NA,                 NA,               NA,         NA,                  NA,             0.50,
            0.46321,   "Germany",             0.5,            1.00,           NA,                 NA,               NA,         NA,                  0.5,            0.75,
            0.69321,   "Germany",             1.0,            1.00,           NA,                0.5,               NA,         NA,                  NA,             1.00,
            0.77889,   "Germany",             0.5,            0.75,           NA,                 NA,               NA,         NA,                  NA,             0.75,
            1.32321,   "Germany",             NA,             1.00,         0.75,                 NA,               NA,        0.5,                  NA,             0.50,
            1.49493,   "Germany",             1.0,            0.75,           NA,                 NA,               NA,         NA,                  NA,             1.00,
            1.03219,    "Brazil",             0.25,            0.5,         0.25,               0.50,             0.25,         NA,                0.50,             0.25,
            0.48632,    "Brazil",             0.75,             NA,           NA,               0.75,               NA,         NA,                  NA,             1.00,
            0.98981,    "Brazil",             NA,               NA,           NA,                 NA,               NA,         NA,                  NA,               NA,
            0.81818,    "Brazil",             NA,               NA,           NA,                 NA,               NA,         NA,                  NA,             0.75,
            1.22391,    "Brazil",             0.75,             NA,         1.00,                 NA,               NA,         NA,                0.75,             1.00,
            1.70182,    "Brazil",             NA,               NA,           NA,                 NA,               NA,         NA,                  NA,               NA,
            0.90429,    "Brazil",             1.00,            1.0,           NA,               1.00,             1.00,          1,                1.00,             1.00,
            1.01102,    "Brazil",             NA,               NA,          0.5,               0.25,               NA,       0.75,                  NA,               NA
            )
```

I want to write a purrr:map_dfr function that loops over each of the `thingy_` columns (apart from `thingy_MASTER_s`), makes a boolean for whether `thingy_MASTER_s` and `thingy_` is not missing, and then filters on whether the boolean `== TRUE`, and then calculates the weighted mean. For example, the code below does what I want for two columns:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(master_and_blue = (!is.na(thingy_MASTER_s) & !is.na(thingy_blue_s))) %>%
    pivot_longer(!c(weight, country, master_and_blue), names_to = "thingy", values_to = "value") %>%
    filter(thingy %in% c("thingy_MASTER_s", "thingy_blue_s"), master_and_blue == TRUE) %>%
    group_by(thingy, country) %>%
    summarise(mean = weighted.mean(value, weight, na.rm=T)) %>% arrange(country, thingy)
```

I could copy and paste the above and change `thingy_blue_s` to `thingy_red_s`, `thingy_yellow_s`, etc., but that becomes very verbose and I end up with multiple tibbles, where really i want them all in one doing it in a function would be a lot less verbose.

This is my attempt:

```
vars <- c("thingy_blue_s", "thing_red_s", "thingy_yellow_s", "thingy_orange_s", "thingy_brown_s", "thingy_pink_s", "thingy_purple_s")
names(vars) <- vars

equivalent_values_fcn <- function(sample, .x){
sample %>%
    mutate(master_and_{{.x}} = (!is.na(thingy_MASTER_s) & !is.na({{.x}}))) %>%
    pivot_longer(!c(weight, country, master_and_{{.x}), names_to = "thingy", values_to = "value") %>%
    filter(thingy %in% c("thingy_MASTER_s", "{{.x}}"), master_and_{{.x} == TRUE) %>%
    group_by(thingy, country) %>%
    summarise(mean = weighted.mean(value, weight_new, na.rm=T)) %>% 
    arrange(country, thingy)
}

purrr:map_dfr(
    .x = tidyselect::all_of(vars),
    .f = ~equivalent_values_fcn(df, .x)
)
```

**Can anyone see where i'm going wrong here? Or help me find a way of doing it using `purrr`?**

Comment: The `{{}}` may not work with strings, you may need to convert to symbols and evaluate i.e. `!is.na(!!ensym(.x))` or may use `across`

Comment: In addition, there are multiple typos.  The column name is `"thing_MASTER_s"` and `not `thingy_`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I have fixed the typo (that was just in my toy data example, not my actual data). Very useful tip re: converting to symbols and evaluating. In the end, I just called the `master_and_{{.x}}` column I was trying to make the same thing on each iteration of the function, as I don't really need it in the output